# setTimeout() function to show popup after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I want to show whatsapp send message after 10 second of loading a page using this code, but I don't know how to merge both of them.

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';
  }, 10000);
}
```

```
$(function() {
  $('#WAButton').floatingWhatsApp({
    phone: '1231231231', //WhatsApp Business phone number International format-
    //Get it with Toky at https://toky.co/en/features/whatsapp.
    headerTitle: 'Chat with us on WhatsApp!', //Popup Title
    popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?', //Popup Message
    showPopup: true, //Enables popup display
    buttonImage: '<img src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/whatsapp.svg" />', //Button Image
    //headerColor: 'crimson', //Custom header color
    //backgroundColor: 'crimson', //Custom background button color
    position: "right"    

  });
});
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i want to show whatsapp send message after 10 second of loading a page using this code but i dont know how to merge this both

Answer (score 1):

just create a function and call it inside timeout

```
function show_whatsapp_button(){
    $('#WAButton').floatingWhatsApp({
        phone: '1231231231', //WhatsApp Business phone number International format-
        //Get it with Toky at https://toky.co/en/features/whatsapp.
        headerTitle: 'Chat with us on WhatsApp!', //Popup Title
        popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?', //Popup Message
        showPopup: true, //Enables popup display
        buttonImage: '<img src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/whatsapp.svg" />', //Button Image
        //headerColor: 'crimson', //Custom header color
        //backgroundColor: 'crimson', //Custom background button color
        position: "right"    

  });
  document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';
}

window.onload = function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    show_whatsapp_button();
    }, 10000);
}
```